# Why does the MVC Core View template not generate code for collections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a view model, which looks something like this:

```
public class OfferEnquiry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a view for this, which looks something like this (relevant part):

```
<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
            </dd>
               </dl>
</div>
```

Notice that there is no code, which iterates through the offers collection.  Is there a way I can ask the template to generate this code as well.

**If the answer is no, then please continue reading.  If the answer is yes, then don't continue reading and just let me know how to auto generate the collection.**

I have written the code below:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Offers)
{
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Whilst the code above works, I wonder if it can be improved.

Comment: The default template doesn't iterate over lists. If you really want it, you could write your own template but that's too much work for something that you can easily add in the result.

Comment: @Haytam, are you able to answer the second part of my question then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The scaffolding doesn't iterate over lists because it would have to make too many assumptions to do so. It's easy enough to just list out key-value pairs from the model (property names and values) or in the case of a create/edit view, labels and inputs. However, for collections, it's unclear how to proceed. Any choice the scaffolding could reasonably make would almost assuredly not work for one scenario or another. The problem is amplified with create/edit views, as creating repeated fields is usually something that's going to require JavaScript (to dynamically add/remove sets of those fields). Not only would it be virtually impossible to write JavaScript that would cover every possible situation, but it would also create hard dependencies that would almost assuredly be offensive to some developers.

Long and short, ambiguity is best left to the developer to handle, so the scaffolding templates take a hands-off approach.

As to your current code. It's impossible to say if it could be "improved" or not, because we have no knowledge of your domain or requirements. It's certainly *acceptable* and will function, but is it the best way or even the way it should be done based on your domain and requirements? Who knows? Regardless, such a question is not really relevant to Stack Overflow. You're essentially asking for a code review, and this isn't the site for that.